# Why can't I import tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I installed the tensorflow following the instructions from the tensorflow webpage, using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev
export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0rc0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
sudo pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

Then I run python and type in:

```
import tensorflow
```

I got these error messages:

```
ImportError: libcudart.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel,
you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory;
please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter
from there.
```

I have google this problem and found answers like https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1244
and
https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/issues/8
But none of them is helpful to my problem.
My python is of version 2.7.6. I was installing the CPU-only version for Linux.
When I first installed tensorflow in the above-mentioned way, it worked correctly and I managed to run some tutorial examples. But today I tried to install the anaconda, which is another useful computing toolbox. When I   installed it, I found that there was no tensorflow anymore. So I installed tensorflow again using conda. But then the above-mentioned error happens. Now I have removed the anaconda, and removed the environmental path added by anaconda. But the import error stays unsolved.
I'm confused about what happened. Thank you all for your kind help!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ImportError: libcudart.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This suggests that the GPU version of tensorflow is being imported. Maybe you have another version of tensorflow installed? If you install all python packages with pip you can check by listing the installed packages.

Comment: Here comes the strange thing. As I showed in the question, I did download the CPU-only version. But it reported this message.

Comment: Thank you for your information. I checked the sys.path of python. I found that there was a path "/home/myname/.local/lib" that contained a tensorflow.  I don't know how it appeared there. I think it is this path that cause python to search for an incorrect version of tensorflow. I can remove this path by running "sys.path.remove()". But this can only remove the path temporarily. Do you know how I can remove it permanently? I have been searching for answers but haven't found yet. Thank you again!!!

Comment: Moreover, I don't want to directly delete this path via "rm -rf", in case some other programs depending on it. I hope to remove the path from the searching space of python.

Comment: You can modify the PYTHONPATH variable to achieve that (https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html)

Answer (score 0):

Create a .conf file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/:

`sudo nano /etc/ld.so.conf.d/nvidia.conf`

Add this:

```
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib  # you probably don't need this line; check
                         # if the directory exists
```

Then run `sudo ldconfig`. Hope this brings you joy.